# Using Arrays to Calculate Previous and Next Values

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way I can use Clickhouse (Arrays?) to calculate sequential values that are dependent on previously calculated values.

For e.g. 
On day 1, I start with 0 -- consume 5 -- Add 100 -- ending up with = 0 - 5 + 100 = 95

My day2, starts with what I ended up on day 1 which is 95 -- again consume 10 -- add 5 -- ending up with 95-10+5=90 (which will be the start for day3)

Given 
ConsumeArray [5,10,25]

AddArray [100,5,10]

Calculate EndingPosition and (= StartingPosition for Next day)

```
                                        -   
                                                  Day1  Day2    Day3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
StartingPosition (a) = Previous Ending Position |  0     95 90  Calculate
Consumed (b)                                    |  5     10 25  
Added (c)                                       |  100   5  10  
EdingPosition (d) = a-b+c                       |  95    90 75  Calculate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finish all the add/consume operations first and then do an accumulation.

```
WITH [5,10,25] as ConsumeArray,
     [100,5,10] as AddArray
SELECT
    arrayCumSum(arrayMap((c, a) -> a - c, ConsumeArray, AddArray));
```